# C# WPF дизайн для локализации

Tags: c#, wpf, локализация

Как контролировать изменение дизайна при изменении длины слов? На некоторых языках слова очень длинные в переводе, как сохранить дизайн в таком случае и не резать слово?

Comment: Это называется `резиновый дизайн` и конкретного ответа нет, как его сделать. Вам придется погуглить этот термин. Основная идея, как я её понимаю, отсутствие жестких указаний по поводу позиционирования/размера элементов. То есть вам не надо указывать, что у этого контрола ширина 10 пикселей. Придется скорее всего указывать, что такой то контрол занимает от 10% до 15% формы, такой-то 20% и так далее, и при изменении размеров формы, её содержимое подстраивается  само под новые размеры.

Answer (score 2):

Как вам уже сказали в комментариях - дизайн нужно реализовывать так, что бы он не был привязан к определенным размерам, то есть использовать "резиновую верстку".

Покажу пару примеров:

К примеру у нас есть окно, ширина которого равна 800. Нам к примеру надо разместить Grid на половину этого окна, как быть? 800/2 = 400, значит можем задать что то вроде этого:

```
<Grid Width="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Background="Red"></Grid>
```

Посмотрим результат:

[image: Result 1]

Вроде как выглядит красиво, но что будет, если мы изменим размер нашего окна? А нечего хорошего, наш Grid не будет занимать 50% всего окна.

[image: Result 2]

Так как в таких ситуациях быть?
На самом деле все очень просто, нам просто нужно избавиться от размера и для этого нам на помощь приходить тот же Grid, указание HorizontalAlignment и VerticalAlignment, да и по сути все.

Создадим новый Grid c двумя колонками и поместим туда то, что нам надо:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="Red"></Grid>
</Grid>
```

Изначально Column и Row размещаются поровну, по этому нам досточно положить наш Grid с цветов внутрь и он займет все пространство первой колонки. Теперь при изменение размера у нас всегда будет ровно 50% окна закрашено красным цветом.

Хорошо, давайте другой пример, к примеру нам в правый нижний угол надо поместить небольшую надпись, как быть?

Я лично очень часто вижу подобный код:

```
<TextBlock Text="Моя надпись" Margin="663,389,0,10" Width="115"/>
```

Этот код мне дала сама студия, когда я мышью передвинул элемент в редакторе. Как думаете, что тут не так? Ну во первых это то, что текст тут фиксирован по ширине в 115, во вторых этот текст может и будет отображаться в нижнем правом углу, но стоит нам чуть изменить размер окна, так тексту становиться плохо...

Так как быть в таком случае? 
И тут все довольно просто, пишите код всегда сами, старайтесь отказываться от размеров вовсе (если не требуется строго фиксировать объект), используйте настройки позиционирования (HorizontalAlignment и VerticalAlignment), не делайте отступы (margin) очень большими (выше 20 уже как по мне через чур). Давайте перепишем эту строку:

```
<TextBlock Text="Моя надпись" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="0,0,5,5"/>
```

Все, теперь наша надпись будет размещена строго в нижнем правом углу нашего окна и что бы мы не делали, она там и останется. Так же и текст, ему будет место, куда можно "вырасти", ибо мы убрали фиксированную ширину элемента.

[image: Result 3]

Вот собственно и все, повторюсь - старайтесь писать код сами, не используйте дизайнер как средство размещения объектов (он годиться только лишь для просмотра), используйте настройки позиционирования и разметки и все у вас будет как надо!