# WPF автомасштабирование при смене вкладок

Tags: c#, wpf, ui, design

Пишу клиентское под WPF.
Суть такова: слева панель закладок справа Grid который меняется при смене вкладок, при клик я вижу два пути смены:
1) использование TabControl. Но тогда все приложение по сути будет в одном .xaml/.cs файле. Нагромождать не хочется
2) Использование:

```
        int index = ListViewMenu.SelectedIndex;
        MoveCursorMenu(index);

        switch (index)
        {
            case 0:
                GridPrincipal.Children.Clear();
                GridPrincipal.Children.Add(new UserControlHome());
                break;
            case 1:
```

У каждой вкладки есть id, при клике меняется отображение поле справа. То есть удаляется текущее и подгружается окно, которое находится в другом файле. То есть для каждой вкладки свой файл. Мне очень удобно, но дело в том, что эти самые окна, которые будут подгружаться я задаю жестко через Height Width. 
На главной странице с вкладками использую Margin

```
<Grid Margin="250 55 0 0">
    <Grid x:Name="GridPrincipal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Grid>
```

Получается, что при смене масштаба окна сохранить пропорции не получится при использовании 2 варианта. Как это исправить?

Comment: В WPF принято использовать систему привязок, ибо это его основная фишка. Поэтому стоит реализовать что то на подобие [этого](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/765122/220553). Что касается отображения, то вам надо не с размером и отступами играться, а с позицией элемента с помощью [сетки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/828870/220553) и др. элементов.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы решить проблему с масштабированием окна с вложенным UserControl, установите параметры в Grid главного окна HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" и у UserControl Height="auto" Width="auto". Это решит проблему