# Почему Gridsplitter обрезает textbox

Tags: c#, wpf

У меня есть 2 грида и текстбоксы, и они обрезаются `gridsplitter` до того, как он закрывает их, как это исправить?

```
<Window x:Class="Films.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Films"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="17*" MinWidth="100" MaxWidth="746"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid"
              Grid.Column="0" 
              Height="Auto">
            <Button Content="Acscess" Width="76" x:Name="Autorization" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
            <Button Content="Go by Guest" Width="76" x:Name="Guest" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,70,0,0"/>
            <TextBox Text="TextBox" Height="34" Width="171" Margin="0,0,0,150" FontSize="20" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <PasswordBox Width="136" Height="25" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,79"/>
        </Grid>

        <GridSplitter x:Name="Splinter" Grid.Column="0" Width="4" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="0,1,2,0" >
            <GridSplitter.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Direction="152" BlurRadius="10" ShadowDepth="2" Color="Gray" Opacity="1"></DropShadowEffect>
            </GridSplitter.Effect>
        </GridSplitter>

        <Grid x:Name="SettingsGrid"
              Grid.Column="1" 
              Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Button Width="Auto" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Height="40">
                <Image Source="C:\Users\gzaly\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\Visual Projects\Films\Films\Pictures\Settings.png" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">

                </Image>
                <Button.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="Border">
                        <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="15"/>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Resources>
            </Button>
        </Grid>

    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: Потому что вы рисуете все через дизайнер студии, а не руками, из-за чего у вас разметка максимально ужасна, ибо позиционирование идет так `Margin="306,155,308,237"`, да и все размеры у вас статичны `Width="136"`. Забудьте про дизайнер, пишите XAML руками! Почитайте к примеру [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/798423/220553), может быть [это](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/828870/220553) и поймите, как правильно позиционировать объекты в WPF.

Comment: Я делал разметку не статичной, потом понял, что эти эелементы должны быть статичны, и закрываться + я не нашел, как сделать отступы от элементов, только от окна

Comment: Я вам показал 2 ответа, которые показывают базовые принципы. Изучайте. Не должно у вас вообще быть позиционирования при помощи отступов, используйте для этого специальные инструменты (сетка, панели, выравнивание), но не отступы...

Comment: Я понял, что нужна резиновая разметка, и как мне сделать то, что я хочу, как в примере, разбивать также на таблицу? Или как?

Comment: Я вам не говорил про "резиновую", это уже на ваше усмотрение, хотите, ограничивайте размеры, хотите, нет, ваше право (лучше не стоит). Но `Margin="306,155,308,237"` и нечто подобного у вас не должно быть! Уберите все это и замените на грамотное позиционирование объектов. Как - я вам уже сказал `(сетка, панели, выравнивание)`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ спасибо за ссылки на ваши объяснения, я переделал, у меня все стало хорошо работать, но одна из проблем осталась. Как мне при закрывании главного грида(у которого размер большой, 2/3), чтобы `splitter` закрывал `buttons` и `textboxs`. Сейчас у меня он не закрывает их, а они съезжают, вместе с `grid`. как мне оставить их на одно месте? Или в моем случае это лучше не делать?

Comment: Вы же ставите сами `MinWidth="100"`, левый контент у вас как минимум должен быть равен `100`, хотите чтоб скрывался полностью, убирайте это. А `они съезжают, вместе с grid` - я лично не заметил этого, вижу чтоб их обрезало, да, но чтоб съезжало что-то, нет.